# Downloading pdf from a site after submitting a form with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pdf, beautifulsoup

I am currently writing a crawler script with python.I am aware of beautifulsoup packages and have did some simple crawlers.currently am writing a crawler for a site which has four dropdown, after select the four dropdown if I press the download button a pdf will be downloaded.I have tried it by requests with this script.

```
post_data = {
'select name 1' : 'value 1',
'select name 2' : 'value 2',
'select name 3' : 'value 3',
'select name 4' : 'value 4',
}   

r = requests.post("http://mydemosite.aspx",data=post_data)
```

which is not working.I want to use Beautifulsoup to select the four dropdown and make a virtual formsubmit and get the appropriate pdf.Is it possible to acheive this(subbmitting a form) with beautiful soup.

Comment: We would need to see the site to have ant hope of suggesting a solution using requests

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes, it is possible, but this really depends on a target web-site and what is involved in submitting a form.

If this is a regular HTML form with no javascript involved, you can use packages like [`RoboBrowser`](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser) or [`MechanicalSoup`](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup) which make form submissions easy. These packages are based on `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` and you would have access to the "soup" object if needed as well.

Comment: thing is I want to achieve this without opening my browser with selenium like modules... is it possible ?

Comment: @noobster nono, the packages I've mentioned don't involve using a real browser - just `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`.